# How to access element passed in a slot to a child component in Svelte?

Tags: svelte, svelte-3, svelte-component

I am developing a table component for my app.  The parent component will pass data to the table to render.  Along with data, it also passes a slot with actions which is rendered for each row in the table.  Actions must be passed as a slot as they can vary.

In the example, what I am trying to achieve is that when the classes select value is changed, the hidden save button becomes visible (only for that row) and this would need to happen from the parent method "onClassChanged".

**App.svelte**

```
<script lang="ts">
    import Table from "/src/components/DataTable/DataTable.svelte";
    import {onMount} from "svelte";

    export let transaction = 0;
    let transactions: Array<Type.Transaction.Bank.Record> = [];
    let classes: Array<Type.Transaction.Bank.Class> = [];
    let transactionService = new Transaction();

    async function loadTransactions() {
        let result = await transactionService.get();
        if (result) {
            transactions = result['transactions'];
        }
    }

    onMount(async () => {
        await loadTransactions();
    });


    function onClassChanged() {
        console.log('class changed');
    }
</script>

<h1>Transactions</h1>
{#if transactions.length > 0}
    <Table rows={transactions}>
        <div slot="actions">
            <select on:change={onClassChanged}>
                {#each classes as tx_class}
                    <option value="1">Class A</option>
                    <option value="2">Class B</option>
                {/each}
            </select>
            <button style="display: none">Save</button>
        </div>
    </Table>
{/if}
```

**DataTable.svelte**

```
<script lang="ts">
    export let rows: Array<[]>;
</script>

<div class="datatable">
    {#each rows as row}
        <div class="table-row">
            <div class="table-cell">
                {row.id}
            </div>
            <div class="table-cell">
                {row.description}
            </div>
            <div class="table-cell">
                {row.date}
            </div>
            <div class="table-cell">
                <slot name="actions" id="{row.id}"></slot>
            </div>
        </div>
    {/each}
</div>
```

I'm not sure how to about this so any ideas / solutions would be welcomed.

Answer (score 1):

If you want rows to individually track state while controlling content from the parent, then you would be much better off breaking up your `DataTable` component into `DataRow` components.

Once you do this, tracking changes is just a matter of having a boolean array the same size as the number of rows in your table, and currying the `onClassChange` handler to accept an index value:

```js
// DataRow.svelte
<script>
    export let row;
</script>

<div class="table-row">
    <div class="table-cell">
        {row.id}
    </div>
    <div class="table-cell">
        {row.description}
    </div>
    <div class="table-cell">
        {row.date}
    </div>
    <div class="table-cell">
        <slot name="actions" id="{row.id}"></slot>
    </div>
</div>
```

```js
// App.svelte
<script lang="ts">
    // import Table from "/src/components/DataTable/DataTable.svelte";
    import Row from "/src/components/DataTable/DataRow.svelte";

    let isChanged;

    // ...

    onMount(async () => {
        await loadTransactions();
        isChanged = new Array(transactions.length).fill(false);
    });


    function onClassChanged(i) {
        return function() {
            isChanged[i] = true;
            console.log('class changed');
        }
    }
</script>

<h1>Transactions</h1>
{#if transactions.length > 0}
<div class="datatable">
    {#each transactions as row, i}
    <Row {row}>
        <div slot="actions">
            <select on:change={onClassChanged(i)}>
                {#each classes as tx_class}
                    <option value="1">Class A</option>
                    <option value="2">Class B</option>
                {/each}
            </select>
            {#if isChanged[i]}
            <button>Save</button>
            {/if}
        </div>
    </Row>
    {/each}
</div>
{/if}
```

As an added bonus, since you now define your slot content per row vs. for the entire table, you can easily handle different select options as well, if need be.

[Basic REPL Demo](https://svelte.dev/repl/8fafaf52747146548d4846aa7ad1cc91?version=3.45.0) with dummy data.

Comment: Thanks, it's important to keep the entire table compoennt as a single component which can be dropped in anywhere.  I got something working which I've posted as an answer.  I'm surprised how easy Svelte made this.

Answer (score 0):

After some trial and error I got it working as follows:

```
<script lang="ts">
    import Table from "/src/components/DataTable/DataTable.svelte";
    import {onMount} from "svelte";

    export let transactions: Array<Type.Transaction.Bank.Record> = [];
    let classes: Array<Type.Transaction.Bank.Class> = [];
    let transactionService = new Transaction();


    async function loadTransactions() {
        let result = await transactionService.get();
        if (result) {
            transactions = result['transactions'];
        }
    }

    onMount(async () => {
        await loadTransactions();
    });


    function onClassChanged(row) {
        row.state = 1;
        rowsView = transactions;   
    }
</script>

<h1>Transactions</h1>
{#if transactions.length > 0}
    <Table 
        bind:rows={transactions}
        let:row={row}
        >
        <div slot="actions">
            <select on:change={() => {onClassChanged(row)}}>
                {#each classes as tx_class}
                    <option value="1">Class A</option>
                    <option value="2">Class B</option>
                {/each}
            </select>
            {#if selectedRow}
                {#if row.state === 1}
                    <button>Save</button>
                {/if}
            {/if}            
        </div>
    </Table>
{/if}
```

DataTable.svelte

```
<script lang="ts">
    export let rows: Array<[]>;
</script>

<div class="datatable">
    {#each rows as row}
        <div class="table-row">
            <div class="table-cell">
                {row.id}
            </div>
            <div class="table-cell">
                {row.description}
            </div>
            <div class="table-cell">
                {row.date}
            </div>
            <div class="table-cell">
                <slot name="actions" row="{row}"></slot>
            </div>
        </div>
    {/each}
</div>
```

This allows me to pass custom actions to the child DataTable component and target the specific row (the active row) and hide or show the save button as described in the original problem.  I'm passing a reference to each row back up to the parent slot for actions and then passing that row as a parameter to the onClassChanged method where I can toggle the state property for that row - which will toggle the visibility of the button.